# Google Sheets: Rename Multiple Tabs based on assocaited cells

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, tabs, cell

Is there a way to rename multiple tabs based on assocaited cells in Google Sheets. All the posts I have tried before do not seem to work anymore.

Example: Sheet1 is Renamed off of Sheet1 Cell A1
Sheet2 is Renamed off of Sheet2 Cell A1
Sheet3 is Renamed off of Sheet3 Cell A1

I've tried this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; //Sheet 2
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A2");//Sheet2!A2    
  var value = cell.getValue();//Added
  sheet.setName(value);//Sheet2 name changed
}
```

And this:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
const sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1]

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A1') sheet2.setName(e.value)
}
```

but keep getting errors like this:

11:09:38 AM Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit  @ Code.gs:6

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"]
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => shts.includes(sh.getName())).filter(e => e).forEach(sh => sh.setName(sh.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue()));
}
```

Comment: That last line (`ss.getSheets()...`) is a corker; so efficient. But also gets around a common problem (for me, at least)- i.e. that I might well have 3 sheets "Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3", but they're not in that particular order.